# SpiderJam email crawl blocker

Tags: javascript, html, web-crawler

I'm using a webpage template, and I found the code for a function by the name of "SpiderJam".  I think this function blocks email crawlers in some way, but I can't quite identify how.  Here is the JS:

```js
function spiderjam(mym, myd){
    document.write("<a href=mailto:" + mym + "&#64;" + myd + ">" + mym + "&#64;" + myd + "</a>");
}
```

And here is how I call it in my HTML file:

```js
document.write("&nbsp;");
spiderjam('myemail','website.com');
```

Here are my questions:

1. What exactly is this function doing?  What does the crawler see when it encounters this on the page?
2. (In your opinion) is this a pretty effective way of blocking email crawlers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All the function you posted does is write a mailto link to the page. Doesn't block a thing. The exact output would be `<body>&nbsp;<a href="mailto:myemail@website.com">myemail@website.com</a></body>`

Comment: Really?  Why is it called spiderjam?  That's so strange.

Comment: _"Why is it called spiderjam?"_ `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`